# Scala Cats async functor

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, functor, scala-cats

Is there some type of async functor in cats? Or a good way to emulate that sort of behavior?

For example something like

```
trait AsyncFunctor[F[_]] {
  def mapAsync[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => Future[B]): F[B]
}
```

Comment: Your signature requires you to have a transformation from `Future[B]` to `F[B]` for any `F`, or more specifically a natural transformation `G[A] ~> F[A]` for all `F`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think so. The signature doesn't need to be exactly that but it pretty clearly illustrates what my need is (ability to map like a functor but with an async result).

Answer (score -1):

cats-effect have [this](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/Async.scala) monad that can describe asynchronous or synchronous computations that produce exactly one result

Comment: Is there a way to make this work nicely with scala `Future` so it can be used with other libraries?

Comment: @kag0 as far as I know, the `IO` monad companion object from `cats-effect` has a `fromFuture` that converts `Future` to `IO` there and then you can create Async computations.